# Dynamic textarea value stuck at blank

Tags: jquery, textarea

After generating a textarea dynamically with jquery, I attempt to grab the value of this textarea and log it which works the first time I try it but the second, third, etc.. time the value is stuck on blank. I am unsure as to why, but the only time it gets a new value for this textarea is when i refresh the page.

```
$(document).on('click','.messager',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').append("<div class='messageSender'>"
                +"<div class='colr' id='content'>"
                        +"<button id='modal-close'>Close Window</button>"
                        +"<button id='modal-send'>Send Message</button><br /><br /><br />"
                        +"<label for='messageUser'><font size='5'>Message:</font></label>"
                        +"<textarea id='messageUser' maxlength='1400'> </textarea>"
                    +"</div></div>");
 });
```

Where i attempt to log the value

```
$(document).on('click','#modal-send',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var msg = $("#messageUser").val();
    console.log(msg);


            $.post("sendMessage.php", { request: "sendMsg"},
            function(data) { 
                                $("#messageUser").val("");
                                $(".messageSender").hide();
                                $(".modal").hide();
                            alert("Message Sent Successfully")  
            });
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: Something else is causing the problem, because the above code works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/2mw9z/

Comment: Thats what I was saying too, but nothing else in this js file interacts with the messageUser id. The textarea is created everytime you press a button on the page called texter

Comment: Could it be a binding issue?  You may need to manually bind the click event to a dynamically created control,

Comment: I use the on() method for both sending, and displaying the textarea. At first it does send the correct message, but without refreshing the page everytime i show the textarea again, type new text, it stays as blank or null value ''

Comment: Could it be that, every time the new textarea is appended the 'var msg = $("#messageUser").val();' is stuck on the first textarea's value and not getting the data of the new textarea?

Comment: I added an incremental number to the textarea id and the message capture value so that each time a message is sent +1 to the id. This actually did make a difference but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was some sort of 'binding issue' as markpsmith mentioned. I had to remove the div and textarea completely with the .remove() method after the message is sent or the message value would be stuck on the initial value that got set to it since a new textarea is appending each time i click send message.

```
           $(document).on('click','#modal-send',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var msg = $("#messageUser").val();
console.log(msg);


        $.post("sendMessage.php", { request: "sendMsg"},
        function(data) { 
                            $("#messageUser").remove();
                                $(".messageSender").remove();
                                $("#content").remove();
                        alert("Message Sent Successfully")  
        });
return false;
```

});